# Getting Azure client/application id of system-assigned managed identity through Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-sql-database, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to use the [`mssql_user`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/betr-io/mssql/latest/docs/resources/user) resource of the [Microsoft SQL Server Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/betr-io/mssql/latest/docs) for Terraform to create a user in my Azure SQL database for my web app's managed identity. I don't have the `Directory Readers` role from Azure Active Directory, so I [need to supply the client id](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/betr-io/mssql/latest/docs/resources/user#using-managed-identities) (or application id) of my managed identity instead of just its name.

```yaml
resource "mssql_user" "example" {
  server {
    host = "example-sql-server.database.windows.net"
    azure_login { }
  }
  database  = "my-database"
  username  = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.name
  object_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.client_id
  roles     = ["db_datareader"]
}
```

This works fine for user-assigned managed identities, whose `azurerm_user_assigned_identity` resource exposes a `client_id` attribute. However, for system-assigned managed identities, the `identity` block [only exposes a `principal_id`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app#principal_id), not a `client_id`. Using this with the `mssql_user` resource causes the Azure SQL database user to get created, but it then fails to log in to the database.

Is there a way of getting the client id (i.e. application id) for a system-assigned managed identity in Terraform, so that I can supply it to the `mssql_user` resource?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `azuread_service_principal` [data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/service_principal).
Just set object_id to principal_id and it will return application_id which is client_id.

```
data "azuread_service_principal" "sp" {
  object_id = some_resource.identity[0].principal_id
}
```